# Excel VBA Type Mismatch calling Private Sub from ListBox_Click

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I have a Sheet that I have put a ActiveX List Box onto, and a function which will update a certain ListBox (it's listfillrange is a named range with has dynamic size)
All the following code is within the Microsoft Excel Objects - Sheet1

Function to update ListBox

```
Private Sub update(lst As ListBox)
    lst.ListIndex = -1
    lst.ListFillRange = lst.ListFillRange
End Sub
```

I want to call this function in two scenarios:

1. When the Worksheet changes:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Application.Intersect("{some ranges}") Is Nothing Then update Me.ListBox
End Sub
```

2. When a different ListBox is clicked on:

```
Private Sub OtherListBox_Click()
    update Me.ListBox
End Sub
```

However when the code tries to call the update sub it gives me a Type Mismatch error on the update line
This is my first time using List Boxes, so my understanding is pretty limited and I can't understand why both scenarios won't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little bit confusing: If you are using ActiveX-Controls, you need to declare the parameter as `MSForms.Listbox`.

```
Private Sub update(lst As MSForms.ListBox)
    lst.ListIndex = -1
    lst.ListFillRange = lst.ListFillRange 
End Sub
```

`ListBox` (without the `MSForms.`) will refer to the "older" Listbox type (so called *Form Controls*).

Answer (score 1):

If you want your code to be universal, this works, without specifying control type (tested working):

```
Private Sub update(lst As Object)
    lst.ListIndex = -1
    lst.ListFillRange = lst.ListFillRange
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to access your ActiveX List-Box, it would be easier to set-it up first. This is where it's gets a little trickier, we would need to set as `OLEObject` and then access the properties of `OLEObject.Object`.

See Modified code below with comments in it (**tested**):

```
Option Explicit

' --- List of Variable on top of your module, so all sub-modules within your module can access them ---

Dim MySht As Worksheet
Dim MyListBox As OLEObject

'================================================================

Sub Init()

' Set up Worksheet object and OLEObject to your ActiveX List-Box
Set MySht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")  ' < -- rename to the worksheet's name you have
With MySht
    Set MyListBox = .OLEObjects("ListBox1")  ' <-- Use the ListBox name you have
End With

End Sub

'================================================================

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

'    If Not Application.Intersect("{some ranges}") Is Nothing Then update Me.ListBox
If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("A1:H100")) Is Nothing Then

    ' ~~~Call Sub the initializes Objects ~~~
    Init
            
    ' ~~~ Call Sub that updates 'MyListBox' ~~~
    update MyListBox
   
End If   
    
End Sub

'================================================================

Private Sub update(lst As OLEObject)  '  < -- Use OLEObject and not ListBox

    lst.Object.ListIndex = -1
    lst.Object.ListFillRange = lst.ListFillRange
    
End Sub
```